# Django-cms installs, but pull-downs and other JS doesn't work - ideas for fixing?

Tags: javascript, python, django-cms, django-1.6

I've installed Django-CMS onto an existing site and while it isn't throwing errors, it isn't working.  In particular, the header on a given page appears when I use "/?edit" but none of the pull down menus work, and very little (possibly none) of the JavaScript works.

Other facets:

- I've done this on a local install of Django with largely development components (for example, SQLite, and the server provided via the django tutorial)
- I've done this with the same result on an install on WebFactional using MySQL and an apache server
- The install is basically the process described here:

http://docs.django-cms.org/en/support-3.0.x/how_to/install.html

- The DB install worked w/out errors and the /admin site has a section for CMS
- The CMS check showed 1 test skipped, and all other tests passed.
- I'm using Django 1.6.5
- This isn't the only time I've had trouble getting django to deliver javascript in a way that executes properly on a project - I had problems with fairly simple drop down menus in the past that I never resolved.

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?  My configuration changes could be seen here:

https://github.com/bethlakshmi/GBE2/compare/GBE-398

## The Local Settings (recent edit)

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*domain of server*']
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '*db name*',
        'USER': '*username*',
        'PASSWORD': '*password*',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }

}

STATIC_ROOT = '*path to the static host in the file system*'
#STATIC_ROOT = '/'


EMAIL_HOST = '* email settings*'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '*email settings*'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*email settings*'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = '*valid email*'
SERVER_EMAIL = '*valid email*'
```

- **domain of server** - the site is hosted on a subdomain: - prototypecms.gbeadmin.webfactional.com, the Allowed Host is "gbeadmin.webfactional.com"
- **db name, username, password** - the correct settings for the locally hosted database.  The website itself works just fine with these database settings.  I can log in with the same info using PHP Admin from the console.  And when I look in the DB, I see the cms_* tables that came from django-cms during a syncdb.
- **path to the static host in the file system** - its a valid location in the server's file system.  The CSS and JS are there and when I download the source page in the browser and look at /static links it references, I get the correct JS or CSS that I would expect from the server.  The host recommends a particular separate area for static files and a particular configuration - which I've followed and gotten working successfully in the pre-django-cms application.  If it wasn't working, I believe the CSS would not render correctly, and it works fine.
- **email settings** - are the email settings for the server.  Right now they are not working and need to be tested and fixed, but I have a large amount of doubt that email settings could be a factor here.
- **valid email** the various email settings used by django in creating a mail.  These are valid addresses relevant to the business.

Comment: This sounds like it must be a `STATIC_URL` config issue, and as far as I can see you're running overrides for envs in a `local_settings.py` file, so in the instances you're seeing problems, what is `STATIC_URL` defined as and is your server set to serve from that path?

Comment: Thanks for the thought, but the default static URL is working fine in this case - /static/ is mapped to the correct location of the STATIC_ROOT and the js appears to be delivered just fine when I view the page source, I can get all the JS.

Comment: Can you post your `local_settings.py` (with sensitive data removed)? You say that `STATIC_URL` points at `STATIC_ROOT`, but really you should have `STATIC_ROOT` as `/var/www/mysite/static-collection/` or similar then use an Apache Alias to pick up `/static/` at `/var/www/mysite/static-collection/`

Comment: That is what meant when I said "mapped to" - the root is a path within my server.  The files are there.  STATIC_URL is "/static/".  When I view the source on the downloaded page, the source files referenced as "http://<domainname>/static/<rest of file url>" are correctly retrieved - I have no problem accessing these with a browser.  But the js is not executed.  I"ll try to get the rest of a sanitized local settings up somewhere.  Scrubbing it may mean rendering it useless, as most of the settings in there are specific to the server internals, which I don't wish to publish on the Net.

Comment: As you say your files are being delivered correctly (viewable in the browser) can you confirm if there are any errors in the console? Also, are the correct content headers being set for the files? Javascript files delivered as `Content-Type:text/plain` for example will not be executed by your browser.

Comment: There are no errors in the console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After staring at this for about 1.5 weeks, I think I found the answer.

The eventual process to the solution was to get the tutorial up and running in the same environment and start slavishly comparing settings and templates.  With a working tutorial, I could see what was there and slavishly imitate it.

The settings.py and local_settings.py was a rat hole - they worked just fine.

Eventual answer was that the pre-existing site and django-cms were contending over base.html and the block for "content" - there was a mapping for "/" in the base site urls and that meant that it didn't connect to a template, and it didn't have any content blocks.  This really seemed to confuse Django-CMS site to the point where it would offer no pulldowns.  Once I got base.html (now base.tmpl) to more closely imitate the tutorial, I was able to get the pull downs working.

The commit of the original solution was:

https://github.com/bethlakshmi/GBE2/commit/8286a9afd6e3ba8688dfefc4c9d888f5a2fd320f

And on the branch here:

https://github.com/bethlakshmi/GBE2/tree/GBE-398

There have been many more refinements.

The areas to look at would be gbe/base.tmpl, and also the landing and landing_page areas as the first thing that got executed was predictably the url resolution of "/" - so that was a particular blocker.

This is the leap forward I needed, but still a partial solution as there is a massive amount of integration yet to be done here.

Comment: What specifically was changed ? Can you show it in code ?

Comment: Updating the answer with the branch with the fixes... eventually, once integration testing is done, we'll pull it onto the master.